# how to use shell command to create local.properties

Tags: android, gradle

`${ANDROID_SDK_HOME}/tools/android update project -p .` only work for ant. But in gradle,how can i create **local.properties** with shell command?

can not use `export ANDROID_HOME` to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "sdk.dir=/Users/alex/bin/android-sdk" > local.properties
```

Using `>` sends the output of a command to a file deleting anything that was there previously. Use `>>` to append to an existing file.

Comment: Might want to clarify that the path needs changed.